# wait bash script till copying finishes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am experimenting on my raspberry pi and I want to run a bash script when any USB device is plugged to my pi. For automounting the USB device, I am using `usbmount`. I have created a udev rule, which runs a shell script at /usr/local/bin/script.sh whenever a USB is plugged. The contents of shell script are :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Device plugged" >> /tmp/test.log
sudo echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
sudo mkdir /home/pi/usbdata
sleep 5
sudo cp -r /media/usb0/* /home/pi/usbdata/
//I have to wait until the copying finishes
sudo echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
```

What I observe when the USB is plugged in is, the OK LED turns on, waits for 5 seconds, and then turns off indicating that the script is finished executing. The folder `/home/pi/usbdata` is created but nothing is copied to it. When the script finishes executing, will the copy process abort if it is in progress? Why the files aren't being copied? I ensured that the USB is being mounted at `/media/usb0/` only and I am using sudo to avoid any permission errors..

Where are things going wrong? :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
...
sleep 5
fn=/tmp/usb-`date +%H%M%S`.txt
ls -l /media/usb0/ > $fn
sudo cp -r /media/usb0/* /home/pi/usbdata/ >> $fn 2>&1
rc=$?
if [ $rc != 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: $rc" >> $fn
fi
...
```

`man 8 sudo` reads:

> > > Upon successful execution of a program, the exit status from sudo will simply be the exit status of the program that was executed.
> > >
> > > Otherwise, sudo exits with a value of 1 if there is a configuration/permission problem or if sudo cannot execute the given command.  In the latter case the error string is printed to the standard error.

Does `sudo` really run without human input of any passwords?

As for your question

> > > When the script finishes executing, will the copy process abort if it is in progress?

The invocation of `cp` will block until the copying actually finishes.  So the root cause must be something else.

Comment: file `/tmp/usb-144013.txt` has contents `total 0`

Comment: removing sudo will also do I guess because udev itself runs this script as root, and as the LEDs are turning on and off, (which needs root permission) after removing sudo from those commands, so I don't think there is need for sudo and so removing `sudo` from all commands

Comment: seems that the `usbmount` itself is mounting the USB after my script finishes execution and my script always finds 0 files in `/media/usb0` because `usbmount` has not mounted the drive when script is running..